# parseFloat('4.2.2') yields 4.2 instead of NaN?

Tags: javascript, parsing

I found this unexpected behavior when trying to break my code... can someone explain to me why this is and what should be the way to make sure the supplied value is a genuine float?

for example:

```
alert(parseFloat('4.2.2'));
```

I was expecting `NaN`... not what I got.

I made a very simple jsfiddle demonstration [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmkJq/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is how the `parseFloat` and `parseInt` methods work. They parse up to the point where the input becomes invalid. They return `NaN` only if the first character is invalid..

---

Quoting the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

> `parseFloat` parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.
>
> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, `parseFloat` returns `NaN`.

---

To check if a string is a number you can use (*from [Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)*)

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Parse back float to string and compare if they are equal

Answer (score 2):

**parseFloat** parses its string argument from left-to-right, until it encounters an error condition, at which point it stops parsing.

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point number. If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -), numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding characters. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN.

So it starts to parse a float from left to right, until it cannot parse it any more.  In your case, things work fine until it encounters the second decimal place.  At that point, it is no longer a valid float, so it stops parsing.

In another example, if you call parseFloat('100ASDF'), it will return 100, and not NaN.

Answer (score 2):

Seems basic enough when you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for it:

> parseFloat parses its argument, a string, and returns a floating point
>   number. **If it encounters a character other than a sign (+ or -),
>   numeral (0-9), a decimal point, or an exponent, it returns the value
>   up to that point and ignores that character and all succeeding
>   characters**. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.